# Saving Records to CloudKit Not Working

Tags: swift, swift3, cloudkit, ckrecord

I have tried to simply save a CKRecord to my CloudKit database but it doesn't work. I have this line of code:

`db.saveRecord(itemRecord) { (record:CKRecord?,error:NSError?) -> Void in  ...`

The error that displays is:

> cannot convert value of type '(CKRecord?, NSError?)

Comment: BTW - when you post an error, please be sure you include the complete and exact error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the documentation for `CKDatabase`. The signature of just about everything has changed in Swift 3.

It should be:

```
db.save(itemRecord) { (record: CKRecord?, error: Error?) -> Void in
    // do stuff
}
```